# How to add filters to the reports created using asp.net core application?

Tags: asp.net-core, report

I have created an application in `ASP.Net core`. I have generated reports in it by using `ASP.NetCore.Reporting` nuget package. But these reports are in pdf file format.
I am trying to add dropdown filters to filter data but not able to do so.
Is there any way to add custom filters to pdf reports?
If not, can anyone tell me which is the best way to create reports in asp.net core application?

Comment: what you want is some kind of dynamic (interactive) report. That kind of report requires a report viewer (could be rendered by web, desktop ui, mobile ui). Here you just need to design a web page to show your report. Once exported (after user selecting all the filters he wants), it will become a static report (rendered in pdf).

Comment: Can you share the ASP.NetCore.Reporting nuget package link? If you are using the [AspNetCore.Reporting](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNetCore.Reporting) package,  it's Nuget entry has this warning: NOTE: This package is not finished yet.
The project site is unavailable. You might be better off looking for an alternative.

Comment: @ZhiLv I have used the same package which you have mentioned in your comment. Can you please suggest an alternative? May whole project is created in ASP.Net core, so I am looking for an alternative in .Net core only

Comment: @sweety, Since you want to filter the data, you can create reports page and add custom filter, then display the result in the report page base on the filter result, check [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/search?view=aspnetcore-5.0). Besides, you could also try to use the [ASP.NET Core Reporting](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/119717/web-reporting/aspnet-core-reporting), it also contains [data filter](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/1184/detailed-guide-to-devexpress-reporting/shape-report-data/filter-data/data-filter-overview).